# Is Xcode the ideal IDE for most development needs, or is app/web/shell/script development not as narrowly approached?

Tags: macos, xcode, python, text-editor, ide

I'm pretty fluent in the basics of web based languages i.e., HTML(5), CSS(3), php, MySQL, Javascript; although now I'm diving *deeper* and starting to tackle scripting (Mostly **Python** and Ruby) & compiler code (Objective-C, Cocoa, Swift, Metal).

What do you some of you recommend for someone who is embarking upon the higher tiers of programming, such as the ones I mentioned above (**IMHO**; *no offense to web dev gurus* ;-) ); should I use the basic text editor & up (BBEdit, TextWrangler, ATOM, Sublime Text) and create my own file hierarchy by hand, or should I learn with the assistance of an IDE like Xcode, Dreamweaver, Eclipse (I know it's java based, and rather not use on OS X just from hearing word of mouth), or is there any others that I don't even have any prior knowledge/experience with? If you prefer not to utilize IDE's what is your favorite syntax highlighting enabled text/file editor?

I know this may seem like a novice question, but I'm a "measure twice, cut once" kind of guy. Yet, don't let that confuse you with my expectations, because I know what a headache debugging can be, especially when you're twenty or so versions already down the line, and are now establishing a small to medium sized user base, and people are posting support comments/inquiries on your software's Git page/repository, *and you're beginning to run out of answers...* 
:-O

Answer (score 2):

#### I have broken down this into several parts:

### For Scripting Languages

---

1. IDLE... It sucks!
2. Edit it any one of the text editors (your choice, but i suggest sublime or brackets) and the run in terminal
3. Use something like pycharm, it is a nice cross between something like xcode and just a text editor

### For Programming Languages

---

1. For languages like Obj-C, C and C++ you have a couple of options like **Codeblocks**, **Xcode** and **Eclipse**. With Codeblocks, people either hate it or love it (I hate it). Eclipse is versatile but clunky, and Xcode... Xcode I really enjoy it, it is cool, easy-to-use and fun. Probably just starting out, go with Xcode.
2. For languages like swift, you have not many choices but Xcode.

---

### Comparisons

---

### Scripting Language Editors

Idle: Simple. Limited options and customization.

Sublime Text 2/3: More complex. Tons of extensions and customizations.

Brackets: Simple but complex. tons of themes. Still very new.

Atom: Large app size. Nice looking. Has a sublime-esk.

### Programming Language IDE's

Xcode: Easy to use. tons of support. Large community.

Codeblocks: Clunky. * opinion * bad GUI. Has been around for a while.

Eclipse: Versatile, old,large community.

## Conclusion

---

In the end, this question, boils down to opinion. What do you find is good?

For me I use brackets and sublime for scripting, and Xcode for programming.

For you as a beginner, start by looking at sublime text 2 or 3 and Xcode.